# Push Notification IONIC

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic, push-notification

Estou fazendo um projeto Mobile em Angular/Cordova/IONIC, porem estou na fase do `push notification`, já que ele é um projeto a parte.

Testei vários tutoriais na web, até o do próprio `IONIC` , mas não funciona, alguém tem alguma dica? um 'git', um manual simples. Abraço

Answer (score 1):

[Neste link](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch) tem a documentação oficial, eu usaria isto no meu projeto.
E [neste link](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/push-notifications-using-ionic-framework) tem uma documentação mais completa e video.
Também estou trabalhando com Ionic e mais para frente também terei que usar push.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema recentemente, ao assistir esse video com o passo a passo eu consegui implementar corretamente o [ionic push](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udpCIBdwCus)